# git log contain commit for another branch, how to separate commit beween branch

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

How to separate changes between branch?
for example:

1. I create new branch with name BRANCH-1, made a changes, and commit the changes
2. I create new branch with name BRANCH-2, made a changes, and commit the changes.
3. I create new branch with name BRANCH-3, made a changes, and commit the changes.

my problem is, BRANCH-2 contain commit & changes from BRANCH-1

and BRANCH-3 contain commit & changes from BRANCH-1 and BRANCH-2

how to separate the changes and commit on each branch?

Thanks

Comment: If I make some assumptions about the trees from which you're creating each of those branches, I might try something like `git diff BRANCH-1..BRANCH-2 > b2-changes.patch` to get a patch with just the BRANCH-2 changes and then similarly `git diff BRANCH-2..BRANCH-3 > b3-changes.patch` to get just the BRANCH-3 changes. With those patch files containing what I want, just get each of your branches to the desired before-patch state and then do `git apply b2-changes.patch` or `git apply b3-changes.patch` on the appropriate branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those commits are in fact on *all* of those branches.

Consider the following.  We start with a single branch named `main`.  The name `main` locates one specific commit, with one specific hash ID `H`.  (The real hash ID is some big ugly random-looking thing, hence the use of uppercase letters as stand-ins.)

Commit `H` contains two things:

- a source snapshot—a full copy of every file as it appears in the latest commit; and
- some *metadata* that holds stuff like the name and email address of the person who made the commit.

The metadata in commit `H` contains the hash ID of some *earlier* commit.  We say that `H` *points to* the earlier commit, and the name `main` *points to* commit `H`:

```
            <-H   <--main
```

The hash ID *inside* `H` itself is that of some other commit, so let's draw in that commit, which we'll call `G`:

```
        <-G <-H   <--main
```

Of course, earlier commit `G` points to some yet-earlier commit `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--main
```

and so on down the line.  Eventually we run out of "earlier" commits because we hit the very first one.  Getting slightly lazy about drawing the arrows, this gives us a more complete picture:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` tells us that we did a `git checkout main`.

Let's now add one new branch name, such as `develop`.  Git *requires* that a *branch name* contain the hash ID of some valid, existing commit.  Which of these commits should we use?  The most obvious candidate is the current and latest commit, `H`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

If we now check out `develop`, the special name `HEAD`, which remembers which *branch name* is the *current branch*, moves:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

We are still *using* commit `H`.  We're just using it *through* the name `develop`.

Which branch(es) are the commits on?  All commits are, pretty obviously, on *both branches*.

When we make a *new* commit, Git will:

- package up all of the source files as a new snapshot;
- add some metadata, with the right name and email address from `user.name` and `user.email` (those can't possibly be lies: they must be right!), "now" as the date-and-time, and so on.

Git will get the log message from us or from the `-m` argument, and will use the *current commit* as the place that the new commit will point backwards to:

```
                       I
                      /
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Because we are `on branch develop`, as `git status` will say, Git will store *new* commit `I`'s hash ID into the name to which `HEAD` is attached, `develop`, like this:

```
                       I   <-- develop (HEAD)
                      /
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Which commits are on branch `develop`?  *All of them*, just as before.  It's not the case that *only* commit `I` is on `develop`.  *All* the commits are on `develop`.  It's just that commits up through `H` are *also* on `main`.

If we now `git checkout main`, Git will:

- remove all the files that go with commit `I`;
- extract all the files that go with commit `H`; and
- attach `HEAD` to `main`.

The result is:

```
                       I   <-- develop
                      /
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Nothing has changed *in the commits and branches in the repository*, except for where `HEAD` is attached; but our *working tree* (and Git's index or *staging area*) are now updated to match commit `H` again.

If we now create another new branch name `topic`, and switch to it, we get:

```
                       I   <-- develop
                      /
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main, topic (HEAD)
```

If we now make another *new commit*, we get:

```
                       I   <-- develop
                      /
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main
                      \
                       J   <-- topic (HEAD)
```

This is what branches are all about, in Git: they're *ways to find commits*.

It is the *commits* that are all important.  Each commit stores a full snapshot of *every* file, in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  So if commits `H`, `I`, and `J` all share most of their files, they literally *share* the files, even though each one has its own full copy.  (This sharing is enabled *because* the contents are read-only.)

To see what *changed* in any given commit, Git simply follows the commit's internal backwards arrow to its parent.  That parent has a snapshot too.  Whatever files are *the same* in both commits are not changed, and since Git is doing de-duplication, it can find this out very fast.  For files that *are* changed, Git compares their content to see what changed, and shows you a diff (this is computed on demand, not stored in the commit).

To make branches be "independent", just start them all far enough back.  Here, branch `topic` and branch `develop` both started from commit `H` on `main`.  That means changes we made, and then used to make the snapshots `I` or `J`, aren't reflected in the other commit, which started with copies of files from `H`.

(Later, if and when we go to *merge* branches `develop` and `topic`, commit `H`—the best *shared* commit, on *both* branches—will be very important.)